# ionic 3 background geo location stops in background

Tags: background, geolocation, ionic3

I am using plugin 
https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

its working fine, when in foreground, but once it goes to background it stops working. Please let me know how i can handle this.

Code in my LocationProvider's constructor function

```
const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
   desiredAccuracy: 10,
   stationaryRadius: 20,
   distanceFilter: 30,
   debug: true, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
   stopOnTerminate: false, // enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
 };
 this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
   .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
     this.zone.run(() => {
       console.log(location);
     })
 });
```

Function after constructor

```
startTracking(){
  console.log("Starting Tracking");
  // start recording location
  this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
}
```

Calling this function from home.ts constructor

```
this.location.startTracking();
```